# PHP: PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method ***::*** should not be called statically

Tags: php

I have uploaded my website to godaddy.
I am using PHP 7.1.1 in my XAMPP localhost.
Godaddy is using PHP 5.6

Everything is fine in my localhost, but not in godaddy.

Here is the error

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY::isloggedin() should not be called statically in /home/***/public_html/***/***/admin.php on line 6
```

Here is my admin.php

```
<?php
  require("../../includes/bootstrap.php");
  session_save_path("../../cgi-bin/tmp");
  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();
  if(!CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY::isloggedin()){
    header("location:login.php");
    exit;
  }else{        
    if($_SESSION['upriv']=='admin'){
      require("../../templates/***/***/admin.php");
    }else{header("location:../../");}                        
  }
?>
```

my CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY class

```
<?php
    class CORE_ACCOUNT_SECURITY{
        public static function isloggedin(){
            if(
                isset($_SESSION['uid']) &&
                isset($_SESSION['unm']) &&
                isset($_SESSION['upriv'])
            ){
                return true;
            }else{return false;}
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks... maki

Comment: did you modified your class before editing as it works fine.... NOTE: As per psr standard class name should not contain _ (underscore).

Comment: i dont, i only modify the links with ***